# Proof-checking: $a \to +\infty \wedge \exists k \in \Bbb{R}(\forall r \in \Bbb{N}(k \leq b(r))) \Rightarrow (a+ b) \to+\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

let be $a: \Bbb{N} \to \Bbb{R}$, and $b: \Bbb{N} \to \Bbb{R}$, I must proof the following:

"$a \longrightarrow  +\infty \wedge \exists k \in  \Bbb{R}(\forall r \in \Bbb{N}(k \leq b(r))) \Rightarrow  (a + b) \longrightarrow  +\infty$"

Proof: if $a \longrightarrow  +\infty$ then $\forall M \in \Bbb{R}(\exists t \in \Bbb{N}(\forall s \geq t(a(s)> M)))$, therefore also $k \leq b(s)$; if $a(s)> M, \forall M \in \Bbb{R} $ then $a(s)> M-k$, therefore $M-a(s)<k\leq b(s)$, then $M-a(s)< b(s)$ and $a(s)+b(s)>M, \forall M \in \Bbb{R}$, therefore $(a + b) \longrightarrow  +\infty$

is correct?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @AlexR, thanks :)

Comment: Please do not use MathJax-only titles. Some users wish to open the questions in a separate tab by right-clicking on the title. This is impossible on MathJax output because it overrides the context menu.

Comment: @AlexR, I have no idea what to put. Help me :)

Comment: I'd suggest removing the index $n$, since it seems to be unused. This improves readability.

Comment: ah ok.. thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You claim can be formulated in a readable way:

> If $a_n \to\infty\ (n\to\infty)$ and $b_n$ is bounded from below by a constant $k\in\mathbb R$, then the sum $a_n+ b_n \to\infty\ (n\to\infty)$

The proof of that is quite elementary. Let $M\in\mathbb R$ be given. Then, since $a_n\to\infty$, there exists $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $a_n > M - k \quad \forall\ n > N$
For $n>N$ it therefor also holds
$$a_n + b_n > M-k + b_n \ge M - k+k = M$$
Which proves $a_n + b_n \to\infty$, as claimed.

---

Now let's tear apart your proof, noting that my notation is $a_n = a(n)$:
 1. $a\to\infty \Rightarrow \forall\ M\in\mathbb R\ \exists\ t\in N$ (call this $t(M)$), such that $a_s > M \quad\forall\ s\ge t$.
this is okay (just the definition)
 2. $k \le b(s)\quad\forall\ s\ge t(M)$, okay - this was required
 3. $a(s) > M \quad\forall\ M\in\mathbb R$ *not okay* you claim $a(s) = \infty$ already here
 4. $a(s) > M - k \quad\forall\ s\ge t(M)$, okay - since $M-k<M<a(s)$ from step 1
 5. $M- a(s) < k \le b(s) \quad\forall\ s\ge t(M)$ okay
 6. $\Rightarrow a(s) + b(s) > M \quad\forall\ s\ge t(M)$ good. We are done now.

Summary: Step 3 is bogus, it must be left out. Also, dont forget to take all the quantors ($\forall\ s\ge t(M)$) with you, once a restriction pops up, else the statements are false, because they are not valid without further constraints (here: $s$ must be greater than $t(M)$)

Comment: thanks for comment and hint :) ..

Comment: @Soviet Happy to help, I've taken the time to talk though your own proof, please take the time to read it :)

Comment: ok.. I understand... thanks soo much for explanation ;)